# Login with facebook gives different ids in iOS and Android. How to handle server side?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

This is my situation:

1. User performs the login using facebook;
2. After success a request is made to server, passing the facebook id. If server finds something, it means that user exists, else it means user needs to create an account.

The problem is that facebook is giving to me different ids. Suppose user logs in iOS. After he tries to log in Android. The server response is he doesn't exist because facebook is giving different ids depending on the mobile operational system. Has anybody faced similar situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook gives each app an "app-specific id" (asid) that is unique to that app. This is to prevent apps from getting access to the user's real id, and also to prevent tracking apps to figure out what apps the user has since each one uses a different app id.

However, if you have the same Facebook app_id and client_token, you will receive the same asid for the user that logs in. So your solution is that both your iOS and Android apps should use the same app id and client token for FB Login.